# Android - cannot update value in database sqlite

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

I'm trying to update value in my database. Response code is 1. But value is not updated after action of updating. I have no idea what is the problem.
Code:

```
private void updateValue(String val) {
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put("lang", "\"" + val + "\"");
        db.update("lang_table", content, null, null);
        db.close();
    }
```

Also I was trying `content.put("lang", val)` - without quotes, but nothing

Comment: what does "the value is 1" mean?

Comment: function update() is type of int. So, it returns 1.  I read, that this is successful response..

Comment: it's not my method. It's method of SQLiteDatabase. My method I posted in first comment

Comment: Since you left the `whereClause` null, you understand that this code is updating every row in the database right?

Comment: Yes, it's ok for me. I have only one row. And I need to update it. After updating I need to open another Activity and get this value from DB. And after opening app I need to verify: if value is not empty - go to second Activity. Else - update value and go to Activity

Comment: What is the use of a database, for doing something that could be (preferably) done by using SharedPreferences?

Comment: Actually yes :) I implemented this functionality using SharedPreferences.. But for the future it's very interesting to know why I cannot update value..